# {"timestamp":1692775020941,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/actuator/info"}

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

can you suggest a sample project on integration springboot openapi3 on springboot actuator  without using actuator dependency. along with application properties ,pomfile and sample code.mandatory dependency is spring org.doc openapi

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.